# java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground() while upload in google play store

Tags: java, android

I got problem in doinbackground(), i already test in emulator and its woriking well. but if i upload to playstore, then this error show up, wat should i do with this problem ? somebody help me pls

i tried anything to fix this. but to hard to test it, because in emulator or i debug to my android its working well this error didnt show up. but if i upload to google play store, this errors showup. sorry for my bad english

```
package com

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.crowdfire.cfalertdialog.CFAlertDialog;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {

    PrefManager prefManager;
    GlobalFunction globalFunction;
    API api;
    Permission permission;

    HashMap<String, String> dataUser;
    String NIK = "", VERIFIKASI = "";

    String
            txtNik, txtEmail, txtNama, txtHp, txtAlamat, txtFoto, txtModel, txtImei, txtSumbar,
            txtVerifikasi, txtToken;

    String currentVersion, latestVersion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        PackageManager manager = this.getPackageManager();
        PackageInfo info = null;
        try {
            info = manager.getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String versionCode = "" + info.versionCode;

        try {
            currentVersion = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        new GetVersionCode().execute();


        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
        globalFunction = new GlobalFunction(this);
        api = new API(this);
        permission = new Permission(this);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (getIntent() != null) {
            if (extras != null) {
                NIK = extras.getString("NIK");
                VERIFIKASI = extras.getString("Verifikasi");
                if (NIK == null || VERIFIKASI == null) {
                } else {
                    prefManager.saveSessionPublic(prefManager.getVERIFIKASI(), "1");
                    dataUser = prefManager.getUserDetails();
                    txtNik = dataUser.get(prefManager.getTagNik());
                    txtEmail = dataUser.get(prefManager.getEMAIL());
                    txtNama = dataUser.get(prefManager.getTagNama());
                    txtHp = dataUser.get(prefManager.getTagHp());
                    txtAlamat = dataUser.get(prefManager.getTagAlamat());
                    txtFoto = dataUser.get(prefManager.getTagPhoto());
                    txtModel = dataUser.get(prefManager.getDEVICEMODEL());
                    txtImei = dataUser.get(prefManager.getDEVICEIMEI());
                    txtSumbar = dataUser.get(prefManager.getSUMBAR());
                    txtVerifikasi = dataUser.get(prefManager.getVERIFIKASI());
                    txtToken = MyMessagingService.getToken(getApplicationContext());
                    jsonRegister(API.ONSREGIS);
                }
            } else {

            }
        }

    }

    private void jsonRegister(String url) {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    String message = null;
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    String status = jObj.getString("status");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                globalFunction.handleVolleyError(error);
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("nik", txtNik);
                params.put("email", txtEmail);
                params.put("nama", txtNama);
                params.put("hp", txtHp);
                params.put("alamat", txtAlamat);
                params.put("foto", txtFoto);
                params.put("model", txtModel);
                params.put("imei", txtImei);
                params.put("sumbar", txtSumbar);
                params.put("verifikasi", txtVerifikasi);
                params.put("token", txtToken);
                return params;
            }
        };
        globalFunction.getmRequestQueue().add(request);
    }

    private class GetVersionCode extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
        String newVersion;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?*********************")
                        .timeout(30000)
                        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                        .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                        .get()
                        .select(".hAyfc .htlgb")
                        .get(7)
                        .ownText();
                return newVersion;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return newVersion;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String onlineVersion) {
            super.onPostExecute(onlineVersion);
            if (onlineVersion != null && !onlineVersion.isEmpty()) {
                latestVersion = onlineVersion;
                if (currentVersion.equals(onlineVersion)) {
                    checkLogin();
                } else {
                    alertUpdate();
                }
}
```

Exception:

```
 2019-07-30 08:37:34.229 26285-26361/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.surya.diskominfosumbar.onsmart, PID: 26285
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:318)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.a.b.i.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.a.b.i$b.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at org.a.b.f$a.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.a.b.f.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.a.c.l.b(Unknown Source)
        at org.a.c.l.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.a.c.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.a.c.f.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.a.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at org.a.a.b$c.e(Unknown Source)
        at org.a.a.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.surya.diskominfosumbar.onsmart.Splash$a.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.surya.diskominfosumbar.onsmart.Splash$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.Reader.read(char[])' on a null object reference
        at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:435)
        at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:354)
        at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:342)
        at org.a.b.i.d(Unknown Source)
        at org.a.b.i.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at org.a.b.i.a(Unknown Source) 
        at org.a.b.i$b.<clinit>(Unknown Source) 
        at org.a.b.f$a.<init>(Unknown Source) 
        at org.a.b.f.<init>(Unknown Source) 
        at org.a.c.l.b(Unknown Source) 
        at org.a.c.l.a(Unknown Source) 
        at org.a.c.b.a(Unknown Source) 
        at org.a.c.f.a(Unknown Source) 
        at org.a.a.a.a(Unknown Source) 
        at org.a.a.b$c.e(Unknown Source) 
        at org.a.a.b.a(Unknown Source) 
        at com.surya.diskominfosumbar.onsmart.Splash$a.a(Unknown Source) 
        at com.surya.diskominfosumbar.onsmart.Splash$a.doInBackground(Unknown Source) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:304) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some code that involves a line reader that isn't included in your post that is throwing a null pointer exception:

```
 ...Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.io.Reader.read(char[])' on a null object reference
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:435)..
```